# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: bash, command-line, mysql

I've been struggling with this issue for a really long time.  Can someone please advise me on how to get mysql working?

```
root@me:~# start mysql
start: Job is already running: mysql
root@me:~# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

What boggles the mind is that it shows no mysql processes being run even though the above bash says otherwise.

```
~# ps -ef | grep mysql
root      8968  1631  0 15:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: Does this file exist? `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` Delete it. It is a stale socket file. Then try to start.

Comment: mysqld directory is already empty =(

Comment: Hmm? This is for the socket file. 'ls -la /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' Got it? Delete it.

Comment: already tried that =(

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

use the command `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and change the bind address to your **local host or 127.0.0.1** then save and close the my.cnf window.

Then run the below command

```
sudo service mysql start
```

then try login `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

check following steps:-

1) in my.cnf check the scoket location

2)check the mysql data directory permissions .

3)use following if u don't have password 
 mysql -uroot -p 
password:just press enter

Answer (score 0):

In spite of it seems that using start and stop it is the new standard way to launch daemons, I still prefer the old way (in fact, I think that the new way never worked for me) so I stopped trying to use it):

> /etc/init.d/mysql start

Have you tried it? Because it looks like start it isn't starting mysql as ps showed.

Comment: Yeah I get an error message that says it won't work using that method and I have to use the "service mysql start"

Comment: I get a message like that, but it starts anyway. Have you tried ps -ef | grep mysql after /etc/init.d/mysql start.

Answer (score 0):

just type this code in terminal

```
sudo opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root
```

or

```
sudo opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

if you have set a password.

Answer (score -2):

type this in a terminal

`mysql -u root -p`

then enter your password

Comment: I can't, it brings up the same error message as above when I try to do that.